# Does the % increase passives stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

In diablo 3, for the demon hunter to be specific, one has passives such as "cull of the weak" which does 15% more damage to slowed enemies and "archery" (with two handed bow) does 15% and "steady aim" which is 20% if no enemies in 10 yards of you.

If I have all of these do I do 50% extra damage or just 20% or even just 15%.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Not only do these bonuses stack, but they stack *additively*. In other words, to use your example, you'd gain the full +50%.

Comment: Which is a shame, because multiplicatively would mean an extra 59% :(